# Count # of records by grouped date?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm a novice Tableau user, trying to help my organization to analyze phone traffic. My data source of incoming phone calls is in an Excel spreadsheet, and is listed like this:

```
TRANSACTION ID    DATETIME    
151313:179805     1/2/2018 9:57
151340:108017     1/2/2018 17:27
151395:176211     1/3/2018 15:27
```

Our total calls per day range from 10 to 50.

**I'd like to count days with an identical # of calls**, and probably make a Histogram sorted by # of calls on the X-Axis, and # of days w/ that many calls on the Y-Axis.

I feel like this would be a simple Calculated Field, but for the life of me, I'm not getting what I'd do here.

Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define an LOD calc, calls_per_day, as
{ FIXED DateTrunc('day', [DATETIME]) : COUNT("*") }

which in effect, prebuilds a little table in space showing the number of data rows for each day. That works if you have one data row in your input per transaction id.

If transaction ids are repeated, and instead you want the number of transactions for each day, you can use the following variation.

{ FIXED DateTrunc('day', [DATETIME]) : COUNTD([TRANSACTION ID]) }

COUNTD() can be expensive on large data sets, so its better to use an alternative when you have the option.

Answer (score -1):

You can use LoD

```
{Fixed TRANSACTION ID :  Count(Day(DATETIME))}
```

Try this and post the result

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of LoD! Example 1. from [this](https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions) actually help a lot once you mentioned it.

I actually flip-flopped your suggestion, make count distinct, and switched Day to DATE to get what I needed out of it:

{ FIXED DATE([Final DT]): COUNTD([Transaction ID])}

Comment: Okay, I've reached another trouble point. 

The LoD is include records, that I've otherwise filtered on Worksheet. In particular, I've got a column to identify whether a call came during business hours titled "Call during BH?". The answer is either 'Business Hours', 'After Hours', 'Before Hours', or 'Weekend'. 

I'd only like to work with Data labeled 'Business Hours'. Would you have a tip on how I could build that filter into my LoD formula?

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data

Comment: Who ever has downvoted, atleast care to post what was wrong

Comment: Sorry Siva, I downvoted because the LOD calc doesn't answer the question. The LOD calc as currently written shows how the # of data rows with a non-null DATETIME per transaction. That is all COUNT() does, returns the # of records that have a non-null value for a field. He wanted the #records per day, not per transaction. Whatever follows "per" in English is a clue for what should follow "FIXED" in an LOD. Jason D figured that out and modified the calc as in his second comment. If you update the LOD, I'll upvote.

Comment: @AlexBlakemore NP Alex.. not the problem of down vote or up vote just want to know what problem does experts see in my answer... Thanks for Clarification will surely change my perspective towards these kind of questions.... thanks